# Erase element iterating in a while loop

Tags: c++, deque

I try to remove elements in deque iterating a while loop. However seems that after erasing one element,the loop skip the next element .
The code is the following

```
 Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <deque>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

deque<int*> queue;
int main()
{
  int * a1 = new int(0);
  int * a2 = new int(2);
  int * a3 = new int(3);
  int * a4 = new int(4);
  int * a5 = new int(5);
  queue.push_back(a1);
  queue.push_back(a2);
  queue.push_back(a3);
  queue.push_back(a4);
  queue.push_back(a5);

    deque<int * >::iterator it = queue.begin();

    while(it != queue.end())
    {
       std::cout << "Element :" << **it << std::endl;
       //remove all elements are divided by 2
       if((**it&1) == 0)
       {
        deque<int * >::iterator cur = (it+1);
        std::cout << "Erase " << **it << std::endl;
        queue.erase(std::remove(queue.begin(), queue.end(), *it), queue.end());
        delete *it;
        it = cur;
       }
       else
       {
           ++it;
       }
    }
    std::cout << "End" << std::endl;     
}
```

The output is the following

*Element :0
Erase 0

Element :3

Element :4
Erase 4

End*

Seems that the the element 2 and 5 were skipped.

Comment: [`std::deque<>::erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/erase): _"**All iterators** and references **are invalidated**, **unless** the erased elements are **at the end or the beginning of the container**, in which case only the iterators and references to the erased elements are invalidated"_.

Comment: Don't modify the data structure while iterating it!

Comment: That means just do queue.erase(it) . Is this ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have undefined behaviour, because you are dereferencing an invalid iterator at `delete *it;`. To fix your immediate problem, you need something like

```
int * to_del = *it;
it = queue.erase(it);
delete to_del;
```

However, you should also avoid using `int *` where `int` is sufficient, and writing loops when there is something applicable in `<algorithm>`

```
bool is_even(int i) { return (i % 2) == 0; }

std::deque<int> queue { 0, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
queue.erase(std::remove_if(queue.begin(), queue.end(), is_even), queue.end());
```

Comment: Or, from C++20 and onwards, as per [\[deque.erasure\]/2](https://eel.is/c++draft/deque.erasure#2), `std::erase_if(queue, [](int x) { return (i % 2) == 0; });`.